# Citrix Sever not supporting Access 2003, The expression on Click

Tags: ms-access, citrix

We are using a legacy MS-Access 2003 application through CITRIX Server. When users try to click buttons, error message pops up.
**The expression on click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Object or class does not support the set of events.

- *The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user defined function, or [Event Procedure]
- *There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro
  **

---

If we bypass CITRIX server and try to access the same database through DRIVE, we don’t get this error message. Please help!!

Comment: Please provide the expression

Comment: Sounds like [broken references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310803/how-to-resolve-reference-issues-in-an-access-database).

Comment: Thank you Andre for the suggestion. Do you have any ideas which Available References should be checked so that running MS-Access through CITRIX server does not give such error message. I even changed macro security level from medium to low.

Comment: Citrix has its own challenges. Thus, I once wrote an article on how to [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html) which uses a VBScript to take care of the plumbing

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth, this message comes even while clicking go back buttons

Comment: @BDMr. That isn't an expression. Buttons can be mapped to expressions

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth, everything is good while we run locally, only this message comes once we run through CITRIX.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth It might be from the following script
    DocName = "Monthly Schedule"
    DoCmd.OpenReport DocName, A_PREVIEW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting from .mdb (Access 2003) to .accdb (Access 2016) resolved this issue.

Comment: While 2003 is a WHOPPING 15 years old, and I betting that this is the ONLY software that you running that’s 15 years old. However, upgrading to 2016 unlikely the reason why this worked. Why this worked, is that during the upgrade, likely your references were fixed. The other simple issue is you needed to compile the 2003 code on the server that was running the SAME version of Access 2003.

Comment: And it was not clear you were using an mde, or an mdb? (you should be using a mde). And for the 2016, you should be using an accDE. And in a terminal services/citrix environment, you should be using the msi version of Access, NOT the CTR version.